# Why did it delete key a and key c, instead of just key c?

Tags: python

I am working on a program to delete blank values from lists inside dictionaries, however if the entire value consists of a single array that holds only a single space, I need to delete the element containing the single space.

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(theDict) :
    stuff=[]
    for key2 in theDict.keys():
        for value2 in theDict.values(): 
            if value2 == [' ']:
                print key2
                del theDict[key2]
                print "hi"

    print theDict
    for key,value in theDict.iteritems():
        for d in value:
            print value
            if d != ' ':
                    stuff.append(d)    
            theDict[key]=stuff
        stuff=[]

    return theDict
print CleanWhiteSpace({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[' ']})
```

I only want this to delete key c.

Comment: thank you everyone who helped, i solved my problem in 5 minutes, my personal stackoverflow record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each key, you should only look at a single value, rather than looping over `theDict.values()`.

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(theDict) :
    stuff=[]
    for key2 in theDict.keys():  # this is the line I changed
        if theDict[key2] == [' ']:
            print key2
            del theDict[key2]
            print "hi"

    print theDict
    for key, value in theDict.iteritems():
        for d in value:
            print value
            if d != ' ':
                    stuff.append(d)
            theDict[key]=stuff
        stuff=[]

    return theDict
print CleanWhiteSpace({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[' ']})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your nested loop

```
for key2 in theDict.keys():
    for value2 in theDict.values(): 
        if value2 == [' ']:
            print key2
            del theDict[key2]
            print "hi"
```

loops over all values for every single key.  The result depends on the order the dictionary decides to return the keys in – you might even end up with an empty dictionary if the key `"c"` is visited last.

What you want is the following (Python 2.x):

```
for key, value in theDict.items():
    if value == [" "]:
        del theDict[key]
```

Wouldn't you also need to delete values that only consist of *two* space entries?  In this case, it would be easier to first delete the spaces, and afterwards remove all empty lists:

```
d = {}
for key, value in theDict.iteritems():
    d[key] = [x for x in value if x != " "]
return {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v}
```

Comment: wont that return the error where u can't modify the dictionary you are iterating?

Comment: @WebMaster: `dict.items()` returns a list of the items in Python 2.x.  You are iterating of that list, not over the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have pointed out the problems in your existing code, however, there is a much better solution to this problem:

```
{key: values for key, values in ((key, [item for item in values if not item == " "]) for key, values in data.items()) if values}
```

Here we use a combination of [dict and list comprehensions, along with a generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY). We first use a generator expression to take each of the dictionary items and strip any single space strings from the lists. We then use a dict comprehension to reconstruct a dictionary from this data, ignoring any items with empty values (they have all been removed).

As always, use `dict.iteritems()` or `dict.viewitems()` in 2.x.

Edit: Remember you can separate it out if you don't like the giant line of code.

```
def strip_items(items, strip):
    return [item for item in values if not item == strip]
stripped = ((key, strip_items(values, " ")) for key, values in data.items())
new_data = {key: values for key, values in stripped if values}
```

Comment: Ty for help, again, list comprehension is confusing

Comment: @WebMaster This is a bit of a beast. Remember you can split the components if it makes it easier. Look at each part separately and follow the logic. They are very useful tools.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(entries):
    blank_keys = [key for key in entries if all([' ' == value for value in entries[key]])]
    for key in blank_keys:
        del entries[key]
    return entries


print CleanWhiteSpace({'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[' ']})
```

Comment: okay good job, i'll save your example for later when i better understand list comprehension. that stuff is confusing +1

Comment: sorry, yes they are a bit hard initially to understand but there 3-4 times faster then regular loops and can create really concise code in general there nothing more than single line for loops compressed, in a different format.

Comment: oh and dictionary comprehensions, which some are using is only supported on python >= 2.7, list comprehensions have being with us for more than a decade :)

Comment: @samy.vilar Dict comprehensions work in 2.7 and can be imported from the `__future__` in 2.5. This means there is virtually no reason not to use one (not to mention the functionality can be easily reproduced with the `dict()` builtin and a generator expression).

Comment: @Lattyware: No, there's no such `__future__` import.

Comment: well in python 2.7.1 I can do dict comprehenssion as well as `import __future__` http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html

Comment: @samy.vilar What Sven meant was there is no way to import *dict comprehensions* in particular from `__future__`, which is true.

Comment: oh that make sense since its part the grammar, still `No, there's no such __future__ import.` didn't highlight this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why your function doesn't work, but here's a shorter way:

```
clean = {k: v for k, v in dct.items() if ''.join(v).strip()}
```

For example:

```
dct = {'a':['1','2'],'b':['3',' '],'c':[' ']}
clean = {k: v for k, v in dct.items() if ''.join(v).strip()}
print clean # {'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['3', ' ']}
```

Comment: The asker says that he wants to delete blank values from inside all the lists, which your solution does not do.

Comment: @Lattyware: well, the OP seems to have found the solution already, so I'm not going to post any more code. At least my snippet shows the beauty of python to him.